# Horizontal spinner android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

i am trying to make a horizontal spinner in android like this one [Wheel Spinner](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) but horizontally. Any idea on how to do that in android?

Answer (score -1):

How about [android.widget.Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)?

Comment: Gallery is deprecated